# Canvas app not being sent signed_request POST parameter

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook, facebook-apps

I understood from Facebook's tutorial that someone clicks on your Facebook app and is brought to your app page: http://apps.facebook.com/example_app

Then Facebook opens an iframe with your canvas URL and does a POST with the `signed_request` parameter.  That parameter has all the info you need, check it if the user has accepted your application.  If not, redirect to the OAuth 2 flow.  If they have, then the signed_request will contain their user_id.

Unfortunately, I'm not passed any signed_request parameter when I click on my facebook app!  This is what I'm passed in the POST request body:

fb_sig_in_iframe=1&fb_sig_locale=en_US&fb_sig_in_new_facebook=1&fb_sig_time=1316465522.5989&fb_sig_added=1&fb_sig_profile_update_time=1280164553&fb_sig_expires=1316469600&fb_sig_user=111111111&fb_sig_session_key=&fb_sig_ss=222222222222222&fb_sig_cookie_sig=333333333333&fb_sig_ext_perms=email&fb_sig_country=us&fb_sig_api_key=44444444444444&fb_sig_app_id=555555555555&fb_sig=66666666666

Is it the above or signed_request?  I'm confused... how can I get the access_token of the user and his user_id?

Comment: Is this a very old app? You may need to specifically enable this - there's currently a migration setting under Advanced settings for your app which will turn this on

Comment: Igy, you're right!  It was set to disabled for some reason.  Post that as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be enabled for all (especially older) apps by default, there's a setting you need to enable in the App's Advanced settings, under 'Migrations' to enable signed_request for canvas apps

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, what is the option under 'Migrations' called?

Comment: It's called 'signed_request for Canvas' but will be enabled by default (and hidden from that interface) for recently created apps

Comment: thanks it is hidden. The problem was that it was redirecting the url to force www (which I hate) and this was wiping out the 'signed_request' POST variable

Comment: @Igy i can't find this in the new FB app settings and i am not getting any GET Or Post in my canvas app...

Comment: This answer was from 2011 - all canvas apps are sent a POST request now, not GET - if you're not able to see it, check the canvas URL you're using in the app settings doesn't redirect - if it does you'll lose the POST parameters